# Trying to export a SQL table but getting errors with Python + PYODBC and pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pyodbc

Hello I am trying to export a very large SQL table (approx 1.7million rows) into either an excel or csv file, my problem is when I dont specify a chunksize I am getting a memory limit error, I am guessing the data is too large to store in memory. Now that I have passed in a chunksize I am getting a different error.

Error -  VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
values = np.array([convert(v) for v in values])

Code:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd


conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=servername;'
                      'Database=DB01;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')


sql_query = pd.read_sql_query("select * from calltype", conn, chunksize=1000, dtype=object)
df = pd.DataFrame(sql_query)
df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\user\Documents\BackupTest1.xlsx', index=False)
print("Records Exported")'''
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check out this article and see if any of these solutions work for you.

[Bypassing Pandas Memory Limitations](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bypassing-pandas-memory-limitations/)

The message you are getting is just a warning not an error based on what you wrote so if your data exports correctly this may not be an issue but you do some data validation to check. Alternatively, defining the dtype as an object may make the warning go away.